# WebRTC SDP Parsing error with GeckoFX

Tags: javascript, c#, webrtc, geckofx

I use WebRTC between a Browser and [GeckoFX](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/).
But some error occurs in the c# application when I call `RTCPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription()`.

```
Could not process offer SDP: cause = SDP_PARSE_FAILED | SDP Parsing Error:
Warning: Group attribute type unsupported (BUNDLE). | SDP Parsing Error:
Warning: Unrecognized attribute (maid-semantic) | SDP Parsing Error:
Warning: Transport protocol type unsupported (UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF). | SDP
Parsing Error: Invalid port format(9) specified for transport protocol (Unsupported), parse failed.
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: What browser version are you using? What does the remote description look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does this occur?

When invoking
`pc.setRemoteDescription(sessionDescription, successCallback, errorCallback);` your stack is parsing the sessionDescription ([SDP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4317)) from a remote. This

> [description defines the properties of the connection like its codec.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/setRemoteDescription)

And has a [format like](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4566.txt):

```
   v=0
   o=bob 2808844564 2808844564 IN IP4 biloxi.example.com
   s=
   c=IN IP4 biloxi.example.com
   t=0 0
   m=audio 20000 RTP/AVP 0 # m=audio 1 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 0 8 126
   b=AS:200
   a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
   m=video 30000 RTP/AVP 32
   b=AS:1000
   a=rtpmap:32 MPV/90000
```

In your case the remote description contains certain attributes (`bundle`, `maid-semantic`...)
the client does not support. You probably have to upgrade the [Browser you are using](http://community.respoke.io/t/screen-sharing-not-working-in-firefox/231).

Comment: I use Browser is chrome48.0.
And Geckofx c# webbrowser is Netscape v5.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with GeckoFX how old is the version of that? Can you share the remote description? Who is initiating the call? How far do you get?

Comment: I think chrom48.0 support UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF protocol.
And netscape5 support only RTP/SAVPF.
When connect from chrome48.0 to netscape 5 occurs error.
What do you think about connect from netscape5 to chrom48.0?

Comment: I'd definitely try and upgrade to the latest version. These incompatibilities are hard (impossible) to fix from a high level.